# can't update checkbox in django template for loop table from model object, using jquery. jquery doesn't iterate with django loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have a dynamic table using for-loop in django template, it contains a checkbox on each row which I want to update as checked or unchecked from the boolean model object which is already available in the template, on loading the page.
I have the code on template as:

```
    <tbody id="order_list_body">
{% for item in items %}
  <tr height="50px">
  <td align="center">
    {{item.item}}
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    {{item.price}}
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    {{item.stock}}
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <input type="checkbox" id="available" name="available" >
    {{item.available}}
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <a href="{% url 'order' %}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
    <a href="{% url 'order' %}" class="btn btn-warning" >Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>



    //jquery to update the checkbox with the 'item.available' boolean
     <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        if ('{{item.available}}' == 'True'){
            $('#available').prop('checked', true);
            console.log("checked {{item.item}} as {{item.available}} in the true loop");
        }

        else if ('{{item.available}}' == 'False'){
            $('#available').prop('checked', false);
            console.log("checked {{item.item}} as {{item.available}} in the false loop");
        }
});


</script>

{% endfor %}
```

But somehow the javascript is not updating the checkboxes according to the boolean 'item.available' on the load of page.

console.log gives :

```
checked item1 as True in the true loop
(index):197 checked item2 as False in the false loop
(index):270 checked item4 as True in the true loop
(index):353 checked item6 as False in the false loop
```

and the javascript on chrome source shows for the item1 marked as true is :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        if ('True' == 'True'){
            $('available').prop('checked', true);
            console.log("checked item1 as True in the true loop");
        }
```

Could someone please tell me why the `$('#available').prop('checked', true)` is not taking effect and showing the checkbox as already ticked on page load.
If my doubt needs more details please let me know and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a script to keep a checkbox checked when the value is True you can do that inline below is the snippet ({% if item.available %} checked {% endif %})

```
{% for item in items %}
  <tr height="50px">
  <td align="center">
    {{item.item}}
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    {{item.price}}
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    {{item.stock}}
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <input type="checkbox" id="available" name="available" {% if item.available %} checked {% endif %} >
    {{item.available}}
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <a href="{% url 'order' %}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
    <a href="{% url 'order' %}" class="btn btn-warning" >Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```